# GPS Icon wont dissapear when remove updates is called from onPause Android

Tags: android, location, maps, locationmanager, android-location

Hi i am having a issue where the location icon wont dissaprear after calling location.removeUpdates. I have followed this solution.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

// Get Class Name
private static String TAG = GPSTracker.class.getName();

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS Status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS Tracking is enabled 
boolean isGPSTrackingEnabled = false;

Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;

// How many Geocoder should return our GPSTracker
int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

// The minimum distance to change updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

// Store LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER or LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER information
private String provider_info;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    //getLocation();
}

/**
 * Try to get my current location by GPS or Network Provider
 */
public void getLocation() {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // Try to get location if you GPS Service is enabled
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

            Log.d(TAG, "Application use GPS Service");

            /*
             * This provider determines location using
             * satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return
             * a location fix.
             */

            provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

        } else if (isNetworkEnabled) { // Try to get location if you Network Service is enabled
            this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

            Log.d(TAG, "Application use Network State to get GPS coordinates");

            /*
             * This provider determines location based on
             * availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved
             * by means of a network lookup.
             */
            provider_info = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

        } 

        // Application can use GPS or Network Provider
        if (!provider_info.isEmpty()) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                provider_info,
                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, 
                this
            );

            if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider_info);
                updateGPSCoordinates();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Update GPSTracker latitude and longitude
 */
public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

/**
 * GPSTracker latitude getter and setter
 * @return latitude
 */
public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

/**
 * GPSTracker longitude getter and setter
 * @return
 */
public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

/**
 * GPSTracker isGPSTrackingEnabled getter.
 * Check GPS/wifi is enabled
 */
public boolean getIsGPSTrackingEnabled() {

    return this.isGPSTrackingEnabled;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this method will stop using GPS in your app
 */
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    //Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.GPSAlertDialogTitle);

    //Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.GPSAlertDialogMessage);

    //On Pressing Setting button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.action_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //On pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
 * @return null or List<Address>
 */
public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
    if (location != null) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

        try {
            /**
             * Geocoder.getFromLocation - Returns an array of Addresses 
             * that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude.
             */
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, this.geocoderMaxResults);

            return addresses;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Try to get AddressLine
 * @return null or addressLine
 */
public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

        return addressLine;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Locality
 * @return null or locality
 */
public String getLocality(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String locality = address.getLocality();

        return locality;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Postal Code
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

        return postalCode;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get CountryName
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getCountryName(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String countryName = address.getCountryName();

        return countryName;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

When i call the stopUsingGPS function it calls it but doesnt stop the location service, it still shows the icon in the action bar.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
    gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();
}
```

Any suggestion would be gratefully appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really create a new instance of GPSTracker and call functions there. Because you've already started the `Service`. To achieve this, you should implement a `ServiceConnection` with a `Binder`.

In your Service add,

```
private final IBinder locationBinder = new LocationBinder();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return locationBinder;
}

public class LocationBinder extends Binder {
   public GPSTracker getService() {
        Log.v("Test", "GPSTracker: getService() called");
        return GPSTracker.this;
   }
}
```

And in your activity,

```
private GPSTracker gpsTracker;
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder baBinder) {
       gpsTracker = ((GPSTracker.LocationBinder) baBinder).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
       gpsTracker = null;
    }
};
```

And the in your activity's `onCreate()`,

```
 Intent locationIntent = new Intent(this, GPSTracker.class);
 startService(locationIntent);
 bindService(locationIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And then `onPause()`,

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();
}
```

And then `onDestroy()`,

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer, i have a little issue with it though, the startService(location) has a cant resolve method error, when i add gpsTracker.startService(location) it throws a null pointer.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `gpsTracker.startService(location)`.

Comment: i fixed that the problem as i am using fragements i needed to add getActivity().startService(location).  its still not stopping the service, i will investigate in the meantime.. Thank you very much for your time. if i get stuck i will message you. :-)